# Django Form: Filter and display options based on objects created by user in a form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

The current problem is that my form shows the logged-in user all 'decks' ever created. The form should only show 'decks' that the logged-in user created. I can filter the decks from the given user, but I can't get that information passed as the only options a user can select from.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='Default.png', upload_to='images/')

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
    
class Deck(models.Model):
    deck = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_cedh = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deck

class Game(models.Model):
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    wincon = models.ForeignKey(Wincon, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tournament = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    num_players = models.IntegerField(choices=NUM_PLAYERS_CHOICE, default=4)
    start_pos = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=START_POS_CHOICE, default=1)
    mull = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MULL_CHOICE, default='1st 7')
    outcome = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=OUTCOME_CHOICE, default='Win')
    medium = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=MEDIUM_CHOICE, default='Paper')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def game_tracker(request):
    user_decks = Deck.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/track')
    else:
        form = GameForm()

    context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/gametracker.html', context=context)
```

forms.py

```
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        exclude = {'date', 'time', }
        labels = {
            'deck': 'What deck',
            'num_players': '# of Players',
            'start_pos': 'Starting position',
            'mull': 'Starting hand',
            'outcome': 'Outcome',
            'wincon': 'Wincon',
            'medium': 'Paper or Online',
            'tournament': 'Tournament',
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your forms and views.py.

In your forms..

```
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['deck'].queryset = Deck.objects.filter(user=user)
    
    class Meta:
        # ...
```

In your views..

```
@login_required
def game_tracker(request):
    user_decks = Deck.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GameForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/track')
    else:
        form = GameForm(request.user)
    # ....
```

Answer (score 0):

We can override the `get_form` method of  our view and modify the `deck` field to only include the `Deck` instances that belong to the current user:

```
class CreateGame(CreateView):
    model = Game
    form_class = GameForm
    template_name = 'gametracker_app/gametracker.html'
    success_url = 'track'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['deck'].queryset = Deck.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateGame, self).form_valid(form)
```

[**`Reference`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38865037/22718477)